# Map of the Imperial Palace on Earth

Tags: warhammer-40k

Last night I read a book that describes places on Earth (hives, rooms and some of the buildings of the Imperial palace). I was wondering is there a painting/drawing of it anywhere in the GW world?

Comment: I wonder if that is not something for rpg stack though

Comment: @Thomas as it concerns WH40k lore,  it's on topic here

Comment: @AncientSwordRage yepp that is for sure only wasn't sure if he has higher chances at the rpg stack there as those tend to have more maps in regards to scifi game universes but theoretically could be answered as easily here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**A map/aerial view of the [imperial palace](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Imperial_Palace) was released with the codex for the [Adeptus Custodes](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Adeptus_Custodes) (8th edition)**

[image]

With the new Siege of terra series GW have released some lovely new artsy maps. All details can be found here: https://siegeofterra.com/.
These are some of the new maps that have been released.

[image: Imperial palace from the siege of terra]
[image: Detail shot imperial palace]

Comment: +1s all around. These are my favorite answers! A question that goes without for a time, finally gets a good answer, and it also gets closure from the OP!